# *ngfor array to ion-list in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am new in ionic 2. I created an array then I want to loop the array to ion-list

my `produk.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-produk',
  templateUrl: 'produk.html',
})
export class ProdukPage {



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    var menu: any[] = [
      "menu 1",
      "menu 2",
      "menu 3"
    ];
  }

}
```

I tried with this code in my html, but it doesn't work

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngfor = "let item of menu;">
     {{menu}}
    </ion-item>  
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: are you getting errors? what do you mean doesnt work?

Comment: Try change `var menu` to `this.menu`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`menu` needs to be a class variable for this to work.

```
export class ProdukPage {
 menu:any[]=[]; //initialize to empty list to avoid undefined/null errors for `menu` in the template.
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.menu = [
      "menu 1",
      "menu 2",
      "menu 3"
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should define class variable.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-produk',
  templateUrl: 'produk.html',
})
export class ProdukPage {

   menu: any[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.menu: any[] = [
      "menu 1",
      "menu 2",
      "menu 3"
    ];
  }

}
```